# Can we replace word contextConfigLocation by foo?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, servlets

I am using Java/JDK 1.6,  Spring 2.5.6, Eclipse IDE 2022-06 . I see file `web.xml`

[image]

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Please focus at this line

```xml
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
```

Can we replace word `contextConfigLocation` by `foo`?

Comment: Obviously not, as that is the parameter name used by the `ContextLoaderListener` to determine which xml file to load (by default it loads `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`. There is a problem with this setup as you are now loading your application twice, once in the `ContextLoaderListener` and again by the `DispatcherServlet`.